# wordpress page how to insert table with pagination

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am generating an html table dynamically using Javascript and replacing Wordpress-page html block with the generated table. How do I introduce pagination into the table display so that I can display for eg: 10 records at a time.

html block added in Wordpress page editor

```
<table>
<!-- here goes our data! -->
</table>
```

Java script code

```
var employeelList = [];
.......
employeesList.push({name: emp.name, age: emp.age, salary: emp.salary});
......


let table = document.querySelector("table");
let data = Object.keys(employeeList[0]);
generateTableHead(table, data);
generateTable(table, employeeList);


function generateTableHead(table, data) {
let thead = table.createTHead();
let row = thead.insertRow();
  for (let key of data) {
   let th = document.createElement("th");
   let text = document.createTextNode(key);
   th.appendChild(text);
   row.appendChild(th);
  }
}


function generateTable(table, data) {
 for (let element of data) {
  let row = table.insertRow();
    for (key in element) {
      let cell = row.insertCell();
      let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
      cell.appendChild(text);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add the scripts where ever you need the pagination.**

$customPagHTML     = "";

$query             = "SELECT * FROM custom_table";

$total_query     = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";

$total             = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );

$items_per_page = 4;

$page             = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;

$offset         = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;

$result         = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT ${offset},

${items_per_page}" );

$totalPage         = ceil($total / $items_per_page);

**For pagination simply use below codes.**

if($totalPage > 1){

$customPagHTML     =  'Page '.$page.' of '.$totalPage.''.paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),

'format' => '',

'prev_text' => __('«'),

'next_text' => __('»'),

'total' => $totalPage,

'current' => $page

)).'';

}